# How i can allow/activate diffrent port for SSH from only one IP?

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

In my system, servers use different ports for SSH. But one of the applications can connect servers with only port 22 for SSH. I can't change the servers' ssh port because of some security rules. Is it possible to allow just one server to SSH connect with port 22(other SSH connections should be connected with defined ports) or are there any port forwarding methods? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Which operating system for the server? Can you in the router do port-forwarding to the right port?

Comment: This type of port redirection can be accomplished in pretty much any standard Enterprise switch.  You might also be able to accomplish it with a proxy, but if the port cannot be changed because of security rules, I have a feeling you won't be able to establish a new proxy that does not already exist.  Have you asked the system Administrator what the solution to this problem should be given your network constraints?